# My VPS send an outbound attack

Tags: vps, ddos

My VPS was sending an large outbound attack 10MB/s. It's normal max 300Kb/s

I've tried searching around the internet, look for some /tmp folder, installed Linux Malware Detect, installed csf with enabling UDP out attack... with no luck.

I think that try to determine what is sending traffic out is the best way to find out what happen

Here is the result of netstat -a -n [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Su4yjGj9)

Here is the result of tcpdump [Mega.co.nz](https://mega.co.nz/#!YEFClCLT!6Q1AcIVoN6G10Oq_6enoEhKWWuGwLzRa2Xd70HUWr-k)

I've tried searching some where but don't have enough knowledge about Linux to investigate. Any help will be appreciated.

thank you.

**Update** output of netstat -s

```
[root@vps ~]# netstat -s
Ip:
    495103797 total packets received
    1 with invalid addresses
    0 forwarded
    0 incoming packets discarded
    493769051 incoming packets delivered
    1204381056 requests sent out
    3692 outgoing packets dropped
    5 fragments failed
Icmp:
    13585 ICMP messages received
    201 input ICMP message failed.
    ICMP input histogram:
        destination unreachable: 10082
        timeout in transit: 3276
        redirects: 3
        echo requests: 183
        echo replies: 2
    240 ICMP messages sent
    0 ICMP messages failed
    ICMP output histogram:
        destination unreachable: 57
        echo replies: 183
IcmpMsg:
        InType0: 2
        InType3: 10082
        InType5: 3
        InType8: 183
        InType11: 3276
        OutType0: 183
        OutType3: 57
Tcp:
    1015004 active connections openings
    5115582 passive connection openings
    15442 failed connection attempts
    452556 connection resets received
    625 connections established
    493650804 segments received
    1183198473 segments send out
    21110586 segments retransmited
    4286 bad segments received.
    450901 resets sent
Udp:
    104609 packets received
    53 packets to unknown port received.
    0 packet receive errors
    104876 packets sent
UdpLite:
TcpExt:
    13815 resets received for embryonic SYN_RECV sockets
    513 packets pruned from receive queue because of socket buffer overrun
    18 ICMP packets dropped because they were out-of-window
    11 ICMP packets dropped because socket was locked
    1945118 TCP sockets finished time wait in fast timer
    120383 packets rejects in established connections because of timestamp
    2393832 delayed acks sent
    20868 delayed acks further delayed because of locked socket
    Quick ack mode was activated 892171 times
    143751 times the listen queue of a socket overflowed
    143751 SYNs to LISTEN sockets ignored
    2669 packets directly queued to recvmsg prequeue.
    71540 packets directly received from backlog
    17015 packets directly received from prequeue
    11857275 packets header predicted
    434 packets header predicted and directly queued to user
    316066031 acknowledgments not containing data received
    137222044 predicted acknowledgments
    5268 times recovered from packet loss due to fast retransmit
    7584644 times recovered from packet loss due to SACK data
    14306 bad SACKs received
    Detected reordering 14577 times using FACK
    Detected reordering 22980 times using SACK
    Detected reordering 153 times using reno fast retransmit
    Detected reordering 27061 times using time stamp
    30970 congestion windows fully recovered
    165972 congestion windows partially recovered using Hoe heuristic
    TCPDSACKUndo: 30728
    117297 congestion windows recovered after partial ack
    9256669 TCP data loss events
    TCPLostRetransmit: 833948
    732 timeouts after reno fast retransmit
    512652 timeouts after SACK recovery
    508711 timeouts in loss state
    13240706 fast retransmits
    742717 forward retransmits
    3815497 retransmits in slow start
    893992 other TCP timeouts
    TCPRenoRecoveryFail: 1286
    544869 sack retransmits failed
    46724 packets collapsed in receive queue due to low socket buffer
    894292 DSACKs sent for old packets
    477 DSACKs sent for out of order packets
    899625 DSACKs received
    50946 DSACKs for out of order packets received
    111195 connections reset due to unexpected data
    177489 connections reset due to early user close
    55313 connections aborted due to timeout
    604 times unable to send RST due to no memory
    TCPSACKDiscard: 2309
    TCPDSACKIgnoredOld: 23725
    TCPDSACKIgnoredNoUndo: 499117
    TCPSpuriousRTOs: 42473
    TCPSackMerged: 3
    TCPSackShiftFallback: 92353444
    TCPChallengeACK: 27513
    TCPSYNChallenge: 4338
IpExt:
    InOctets: 73868759266
    OutOctets: 1748150154862
```

Comment: `1.` I doubt if anyone is going to download your tcpdump. `2.` I see a bunch of HTTP/HTTPs connections **TO** your server. Where's the _attack_?

Comment: When you suspect your rig to be compromised, the only viable solution is : blast it and reinstall. Moreover, posting a raw netstat or tcpdump capture with no public IP obfuscated while revealing you don't have enough knownledge to handle basic tasks may get things even worst as now everybody knows you are an easy target.

Comment: from a rescue system : ls -al /tmp /var/tmp ; cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs   also check http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16908/is-secureshellz-bot-a-virus-how-does-it-work/71468#71468